# How to attain consistent variable values in proceeding methods?

Tags: c, struct, attributes, global-variables, local-variables

I'm relatively new to C and for fun I decided to create a game where the user gets to choose a class to take on enemies. I created a function that allows the user to increase their attributes, such as strength, speed, intellect, and health. In the event of the user choosing to promote one of these attributes from whatever class they use, how would I enable this change, so that it carries on to other methods/levels in the game?

Also note that the classes are made up as structures, so I guess I'm asking how would I modify structure attributes and have these changes apply to towards the next methods\levels. One last thing, health is not one of the structure attributes, I have it labeled as global variable. I did that on purpose because I have no idea how I would keep that attribute in check.

```
struct type
{
    int strength;
    int intellect;
    int speed;
};

//method that allows user to upgrade their given attributes by one
int promote(){
    int increase;
    printf("Please an attribute to power up.\n1.Strength\n2.Intelligence\n3.Speed\n4.Health\n");
    scanf("%d", &increase);
    switch(increase){
        case 1:
        printf("You strength is now at %d\n", );//Not sure what to put here
        break;
    }
```

Comment: After the comma you can put the thing you want to print.

Comment: Health should probably be another attribute in the `struct type`.  You should avoid global variables when possible.  You can pass a pointer to the structure around, and use that when changing values of strength, intellect, speed, health, etc.

Answer (score 2):

## Possibility1:

#### Using global variables (Easy to implement but not the best)

You need to create an instance of the structure just like you made a variable for the health. Since you created that as global, you can create this too as global.

So after the struct definition add

```
struct type player_attributes;
```

These attributes need to be initialized somewhere a the beginning of the game like in main as

```
player_attributes.strength = 10;
player_attributes.intellect = 10;
player_attributes.speed = 10;
```

Now anywhere you need these, you can read them as `strength = player_attributes.strength;`

Finally coming to updating-

Inside your case statement you can add

```
 case 1:
 player_attributes.strength += 5;
 printf("You strength is now at %d\n", player_attributes.strength
 break;
```

And similarily for other attributes.
You also have to make sure that the attributes are accessible through all the levels, if the code for all levels are in the same `c` file (module), making it global should be enough.

If you are writing the code for different levels in different files you need to add

```
extern struct type player_attributes;
```

To the top of other files. Also make sure that they have the struct type definition visible to them.

This can be be done by adding the struct definition and the extern line to a header file and including it in all modules.

## Possibility2:

#### Using pointer to structure being passed around (Definitely the suggested because allows easy scaling)

Having said that, using globals is generally not a good idea, as also suggested by @JonathanLeffler.

What you really should do is create the instance of the player_attributes in the local scope (the function) where the game starts. Then all your functions should take a pointer to `struct type` as an argument. So that they can read and write values to it.

In your case, your function `promote` will become -

```
int promote(struct type *attrib){
    int increase;
    printf("Please an attribute to power up.\n1.Strength\n2.Intelligence\n3.Speed\n4.Health\n");
    scanf("%d", &increase);
    switch(increase){
        case 1:
        attrib->strength += 5;
        printf("You strength is now at %d\n", attrib->strength);
        break;
        // Other cases here.
    }
}
```

You can then call promote as

```
promote(&player_attributes);
```

Say from `main` where it is defined.

This also allows you to easily create more players at the same time and the same function can handle attributes for all of them.

I hope this helps.